# Alternative way to initialize arrays in Header file without C++11

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, header-files

I've made a class in my header file which creates and populates three arrays like so:

```
class ExampleClass {
private:
    string array1[5] = {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};
    double array2[4] = {20.7, 26.4, 27.8, 31.1};
    double array3[4] = {19.1, 25.8, 27.3, 32.3};
};
```

When building I'm receiving a warning about this requiring `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` to work. It builds fine and works how I want for me, but is this something I should worry about in case I was going to include it in a uni project for example?

Is it a case where there's an older alternative that does the exact same, or was this only possible from C++11?

Comment: C-style arrays as class members have a reputation to be a pain to initialize in C++03, so go figure. :|

Comment: Can your arrays be const statics?

Comment: @Pubby Not going to lie, I have no idea :p

Comment: @Zackehh9lives: How are you going to use those arrays?

Comment: @Zackehh9lives Well, are you modifying the values after initializing them? A static function can work in that case.

Comment: No, just reading from them. More specifically, passing them to a function which reads from then, from another function.

Comment: @Zackehh9lives well, this could work: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8z64aAuB

Comment: Every instance of your ExampleClass would have those members. You're using the new "non-static data member initialization". It seems a little waste, you may look for a static member solution instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this something I should worry about in case I was going to include it in a uni project for example?

If you're writing a project for an assignment you should pay attention to the requirements of the assignment. It should specify a platform, compiler, and build flags that your code must build and run on. If those requirements allow you to use C++11 then you're fine, if they don't then you'll have to find an alternative. And remember to always test your work on the platform, compiler, etc. that the graders will be using.

> Is it a case where there's an older alternative that does the exact same, or was this only possible from C++11?

There is no pre-C++11 alternative that does exactly the same thing; prior to C++11 it was impossible to specify an initializer for member arrays. The closest you could get was to allow the default initialization to occur and then re-initialize the array in the constructor:

```
struct S {
    string array1[5];
    S() {
        string init_values[5] = {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};
        for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
            array1[i] = init_values[i];
        }
    }
};
```

C++11 introduced uniform initialization:

```
struct S {
    string array1[5];
    S() : array1{"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"}
    {}
};
```

And in-class initialization:

```
struct S {
    string array1[5] {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only reading from the arrays (as you said in the comments), add `const`.

**CAUTION:** Without `const` and when you start modifying values, the following will not work as expected!

The following is the best I could think of in C++03. While you *could* put everything into the header file, I don't think it's a good idea. I'll show how to do it with a header and an implementation file. If you really need everything in the header and you can't figure it out how to adapt the following code, ask.

We start by creating a header file `foo.hpp`:

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

#include <string>

class ExampleClass {
private:
  const std::string (&array1)[5];
  const double (&array2)[4];
  const double (&array3)[4];

  ExampleClass(); // you need ctors to initialize the non-static members
};

#endif // FOO_HPP
```

Now that you have the header, create the implementation file `foo.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.hpp"

namespace
{
  const std::string global_array1[5] = {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};
  const double global_array2[4] = {20.7, 26.4, 27.8, 31.1};
  const double global_array3[4] = {19.1, 25.8, 27.3, 32.3};
}

// define your ctor(s)
ExampleClass::ExampleClass()
  : array1( global_array1 ),
    array2( global_array2 ),
    array3( global_array3 )
{}
```